# How to round down value from String to Double with ObjectMapper in swift

Tags: ios, swift, objectmapper

I was trying to round down value **199.5** from String to Double with ObjectMapper in swift as follow:

> balance <- (map["balance"], TransformOf(fromJSON: {
>   String(format: "%.0f", $0!) }, toJSON: { $0.map({
>   Double($0)?.rounded(.down) ?? 0 }) }))

unfortunately, result is value went to **200** but what I want is **199** instead **200** please let me know how to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This works in a playground

```
let test : Double  = 199.5
print (Int(test.rounded(.towardZero)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 String(format: "%.0f", $0!)
```

This is where the rounding is happening probably, %.0f means zero decimals.

Comment: Replace the 0 with a larger value that suits the precision you need perhaps?